# How to display my taxonomy only once on my archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a CPT "Compte-rendus" with the taxonomy "Années".

On my archive page every time I create a report my taxonomy duplicates, here is a link showing the problem: https://www.noizay.fr/comptesrendus/

And here is the code I use to display my taxonomy.

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) { ?>
     <?php while (have_posts()) {
            the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'annees' ) ?>
      <?php } } ?>
```

I would like my taxonomy to be displayed only once

Thank you in advance for your support

Comment: How did you _get_ the taxonomy terms?

Comment: What is the expected behavior you are trying to achieve? Right now its actually working 100% correct. Your archive page is looping through all posts and all you are out putting is the term + link. If you look, you have 7 2021 and 1 2022 and if you look at the individual pages 2021 has 7 posts and 2022 has 1.

Comment: @Cbroe Sorry i don't understand, just i call the taxonomy for each post

Comment: @MarkTruitt Yes but i want just one 2021

Comment: `the_terms` directly displays the terms for a post - you will need to replace that with `get_the_terms`, then put all the terms you get from all posts into an array first, and then eliminate duplicates in that array. Afterwards, you loop over what's left in the array, and output it.

Comment: Ok I understand the idea but I already tried and it didn't work, I probably wrote my code. Can you please show me?